# Is there any horizontal alternative to core-list?

Tags: polymer, web-component

It seems like there's no way to make `core-list` scroll horizontally.
Is there any web component that offers horizontal recycling list?

Comment: FYI... [Support Horizontal Lists?](https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/24). From Aug 2014, so I'm not holding my breath...